# One-Shot Manga about space explorers whose beds disintegrate each member

Tags: story-identification, manga, space

I'm looking for a one shot manga about a team of space explorers that start dying because of the special beds they use. Each member is disintegrated by these beds till none remain, I think it's part of an anthology but I'm not sure. Could anyone help?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: im really not sure, i only have vague memories of it but i think it was in a sci-fi anthology if that helps?

Comment: Can you at least give us a _range_ of years within which you were likely to have read this?

Comment: Between 2015 and 2017 I believe.